# Django with Oracle database 11g

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, oracle11g

I am new to the python language and django. I need to connect the django to the oracle database 11g, I have imported the cx_oracle library and using the instant client for connecting oracle with django, but when i run the command manage inspectdb > models.py. I get error as Invalid column identifier in the models.py. How could i solve it. I have only 2 tables in that schema i am connecting?

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid column" suggests that you specified column name that doesn't exist in any of those tables, or you misspelled its name.

For example:

```
SQL> desc dept
 Name                                      
 ----------------------------------------- 
 DEPTNO                                   
 DNAME
 LOC

SQL> select ndame from dept;              --> misspelled column name
select ndame from dept
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NDAME": invalid identifier


SQL> select imaginary_column from dept;   --> non-existent column name
select imaginary_column from dept
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "IMAGINARY_COLUMN": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

Also, pay attention to letter case, especially if you created tables/columns using mixed case and enclosed those names into double quotes (if so, I'd suggest you to drop tables and recreate them, without double quotes. If you can't do that, you'll have to reference them using double quotes and *exactly* the same letter case).

So - check column names and compare them to your query. If you still can't make it work, post some more information - table description and your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. The problem is that Django expects your table have primary key (ID), so when your table is without key, it returns Invalid columns identifier.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields